# How to create event with videoconference in Google Meet in C# using Google Calendar API?

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Well.. I'm trying this code to create an Event

```
            CalendarService service;
            GoogleCredential credential;

            try
            {
                string[] scopes = new string[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar };
                using (var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Prueba\meet.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                    .CreateScoped(scopes);
                }
                service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential
                });


                Event calendarEvent = new Event();
                DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
                calendarEvent.Kind = "";
                calendarEvent.Summary = "prueba";
                calendarEvent.Status = "confirmed";
                calendarEvent.Visibility = "public";
                calendarEvent.Description = "prueba";

                calendarEvent.Creator = new Event.CreatorData
                {
                    Email = "email@example.com", //email@example.com
                    Self = true
                };

                calendarEvent.Organizer = new Event.OrganizerData
                {
                    Email = "email@example.com",
                    Self = true
                };

                calendarEvent.Start = new EventDateTime
                {
                    DateTime = start,
                    TimeZone = "America/Mexico_City"
                };

                calendarEvent.End = new EventDateTime
                {
                    DateTime = start.AddHours(1),
                    TimeZone = "America/Mexico_City"
                };

                calendarEvent.Recurrence = new String[] { "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1" };
                calendarEvent.Sequence = 0;
                calendarEvent.HangoutLink = "";

                calendarEvent.ConferenceData = new ConferenceData
                {
                    CreateRequest = new CreateConferenceRequest
                    {
                        RequestId = "1234abcdef",
                        ConferenceSolutionKey = new ConferenceSolutionKey
                        {
                            Type = "hangoutsMeet"
                        },
                        Status = new ConferenceRequestStatus
                        {
                            StatusCode = "success"
                        }
                    },
                    EntryPoints = new List<EntryPoint>
                    {
                        new EntryPoint
                        {
                            EntryPointType = "video",
                            Uri = "",
                            Label = ""
                        }
                    },
                    ConferenceSolution = new ConferenceSolution
                    {
                        Key = new ConferenceSolutionKey
                        {
                            Type = "hangoutsMeet"
                        },
                        Name = "Google Meet",
                        IconUri = ""
                    },
                    ConferenceId = ""
                };

                //calendarEvent.EventType = "default";


                EventsResource.InsertRequest request = service.Events.Insert(calendarEvent, "email@example.com");
                request.ConferenceDataVersion = 0;
                Event createEvent = request.Execute();
                string url = createEvent.HangoutLink;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

The source code is [here](https://github.com/jesustorrst/GoogleMeetTest/blob/master/GoogleMeetTest/GoogleMeetTest/Program.cs)

When I execute the line 116: **Event createEvent = request.Execute();**
I get this error: **Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Invalid conference type value. [400] Errors [Message[Invalid conference type value.] Location[ - ] Reason[invalid] Domain[global]**

I don't know what means this error o with line I wrong
Could anyone help me with an example to create an event using classes C#  from Google API Calendar?

Comment: how is this different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66057925/how-to-create-event-in-google-calendar-api-with-videoconference-in-google-meet-i)?

Comment: Actually is the same, but someone suggets me to publish another one question with the code complete

Comment: you _do_ know that you could've _edited_ your question to include the code, right? (which is probably what was intended)

Comment: sorry, yesterday join me in the page, I didn't know, thanks for the suggesting

Comment: You definitely need `request.ConferenceDataVersion = 1;` but I believe this is also an issue with the client libraries: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1894

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [C# library documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Calendar_1_1v3_1_1Data_1_1ConferenceData.html#a541cab0faeef54a4b3c6d246f5338253) for [createRequest](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Calendar_1_1v3_1_1Data_1_1ConferenceData.html#a541cab0faeef54a4b3c6d246f5338253):

> Either conferenceSolution and at least one entryPoint, **or** createRequest is required.

This means that you should use **only** `CreateConferenceRequest` as this conference is brand new (if it already existed then you would be wanting to use [ConferenceSolution](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Calendar_1_1v3_1_1Data_1_1ConferenceData.html#ab35da0d2f63dcd02201215d90c85993a) along with [EntryPoints](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Calendar_1_1v3_1_1Data_1_1ConferenceData.html#a4dca32d6eb6bbc948d67a8f57671a02a) ). Therefore, simply remove `ConferenceSolution` and `EntryPoints` to leave just `CreateConferenceRequest` which as specified in the documentation is used for generating a **new conference** and attach it to the event.

Comment: I just tried but I keep getting the same error, is it not because I use a gmail account through a service account?

Comment: Have you [set up your service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) and authorization propperly? Can you make other more simple requests (like [Calendar.get()](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get)) with that service account successfully ? Have you granted [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) to your service account?

Comment: yes, in fact I can create events using the service account, the only thing it doesn't generate is the HangoutLink

Comment: So you can create the event you showed in the question successfully if you remove the ```ConferenceData``` part right? Could you try the suggestion of my answer and also changing ```request.ConferenceDataVersion = 0;``` to ```request.ConferenceDataVersion = 1;```? According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Calendar_1_1v3_1_1EventsResource_1_1ImportRequest.html#a63907ce6341a977299e027bf219e3fe6), having it set to ```0``` means that it assumes to not have any conference data support.